# mysql 5.5.32-log with phpMyAdmin 2.8.0.1 cannot import mysqldump file

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a [dump file that I used mysqldump to generate](http://blastohosting.com/php_pos_14.0_db_dump.sql) using mysqldump on mysql 5.5.34 on mac os x. I am able to import using mysql source command and also able to import using phpMyAdmin 4.0.8.

I have a user using mysql 5.5.32-log and phpMyAdmin 2.8.0.1 with the mysql extension using client library 5.0.51a

When importing the database, they get the following error:

SQL query:

```
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client = @@character_set_client */;

/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;

CREATE TABLE `phppos_customers` (

`person_id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
`account_number` VARCHAR( 255 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
`company_name` VARCHAR( 255 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL ,
`balance` DECIMAL( 23, 10 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
`taxable` INT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`cc_token` VARCHAR( 255 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
`cc_preview` VARCHAR( 255 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
`card_issuer` VARCHAR( 255 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
`tier_id` INT( 10 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
`deleted` INT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
UNIQUE KEY `account_number` ( `account_number` ) ,
KEY `person_id` ( `person_id` ) ,
KEY `deleted` ( `deleted` ) ,
KEY `cc_token` ( `cc_token` ) ,
KEY `phppos_customers_ibfk_2` ( `tier_id` ) ,
CONSTRAINT `phppos_customers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY ( `person_id` ) REFERENCES `phppos_people` ( `person_id` ) ,
CONSTRAINT `phppos_customers_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY ( `tier_id` ) REFERENCES `phppos_price_tiers` ( `id` )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;


MySQL said: <b_help.png>

#1005 - Can't create table 'nbofpos.phppos_customers' (errno: 150)
```

If I export my database using phpMyAdmin's export, it works correctly on his phpMyAdmin. He doesn't have shell access or any way to update phpMyAdmin. I verified he has INNODB abilities, so that isn't it either.

I need to generate sql that works will on all situations and I thought mysqldump would be the right way, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Hi, Try to run single query at a time. your dump file worked on my machine

Comment: I was able to fix this for the other user by adding SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; to the top of the file and SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1; to the end. Do you know why mysql would ignore  /*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */; as that seems to do the same thing?

Comment: Awesome,i was searching about it too found this link http://www.troyfawkes.com/solved-mysql-error-1005-cant-create-table-errno-150/

Comment: I am glad I found a workaround, but I wish I knew the reason why it didn't work in the first place.

Comment: #1005 error is mostly due to foreign key this is what i am reading in all blogs. I have no idea why

Comment: If you look at the top of the dump file it seems to have a different syntax for setting foreign keys checks = 0. I don't care anymore, I am glad I found a hack around.